# Error building snapcraft python3-based app

Tags: snap, python3

this is my .yaml file

```
name: ibop
version: '1.0'
summary: Get your pubblic IP address
description: |
  This is just a test

grade: devel

confinement: strict

base: core22

parts:
  ibop:
    plugin: python
    source: https://github.com/aleff-github/ibop.git
```

This is the command `snapcraft --debug` output

```
Launching instance...                                                                                                                                
Executed: repull ibop ('plugin' property changed)                                                                                                    
Failed to run the build script for part 'ibop'.                                                                                                      
Launching shell on build environment...                                                                                                              
snapcraft-ibop-on-amd64-for-amd64-45112 ../project# exit
exit
Failed to run the build script for part 'ibop'.                                                                                                      
Failed to execute pack in instance.                                                                                                                  
Full execution log: '/home/aleff/.local/state/snapcraft/log/snapcraft-20230829-153619.430056.log'
```

I tried to understand the problem reading the log file and i find this

```
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:14.958 :: Successfully installed pip-23.2.1 setuptools-68.1.2 wheel-0.41.2
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.070 :: + '[' -f setup.py ']'
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.071 :: + /root/parts/ibop/install/bin/pip install -U .
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.487 :: Processing /root/parts/ibop/build
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.488 ::   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.643 ::   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.644 :: ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3d35zd5z
2023-08-29 15:37:44.871 :: 2023-08-29 13:37:15.767 Failed to run the build script for part 'ibop'.
```